# Netty's `sync` vs `syncUninterruptibly`

Tags: netty, channel

I tried to figure out from Netty's docs and also Googled a bit, but I couldn't find anything on the difference between a `ChannelFuture`'s `sync()` and `syncUninterruptibly()` methods (apart from the obvious fact that `sync` explicitly throws `InterruptedException` and `syncUninterruptibly` does not). Can anyone please shed some light on the subject?

I'd say it's more "pleasant" (at least for me) to work with `syncUninterruptibly` as it does not declare any checked exceptions. If this is the only difference, then why are both methods there?

Answer (score 3):

You may have a look on [`await()`](https://github.com/netty/netty/blob/4.1/common/src/main/java/io/netty/util/concurrent/DefaultPromise.java#L240) and [`awaitUninterruptibly()`](https://github.com/netty/netty/blob/4.1/common/src/main/java/io/netty/util/concurrent/DefaultPromise.java#L275) to see the differences.

1. In the first one, if an interruption was thrown in the thread executing the future related operation, as the current thread executing the `sync` (or `await`) is different, it will throw an exception in the caller, such that you know.

   ```
   if (Thread.interrupted()) {
       throw new InterruptedException(toString());
   }
   ```
2. In the second one, if an interruption was thrown in the thread executing the future related operation, it will just redo an interruption on the caller thread, which implies you to manage differently the interruption.

   ```
   if (interrupted) {
       Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
   }
   ```

So you can consider the first one as an accelerator, to ensure you test the interruption. But as sometimes you could prefer to defer this interruption handling to another caller again, you might prefer the second.

So the usage is related on how you want to deal with thread interruptions.